# Why constructor is called only once?

Tags: c++

Consider the below program:

```
class A
{
    public:
    A(int i)
    {
            cout<<"Called"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<A> v(5,A(1));
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the output: http://ideone.com/81XO6

```
 Called
```

**Why the constructor gets called only once even if we are constructing 5 objects?**
**How `vector` is internally handled by the compiler?**

Comment: The others are initialized by the copy constructor.

Comment: http://ideone.com/lHX5W

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: you should write that in an answer

Comment: Why one extra copy is done? I mean one object is already constructed,right.

Comment: @Aashish: The first constructor is for a temporary object.  The one you construct with `A(1)`.  That temporary is copied into the vector five times.  It cannot be constructed directly in the vector as you have it. (Well, I guess it could, if your compiler was smart enough.  But it's not.) @Pooya: What are you talking about?  That is definitely not the case.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your class has two constructors and you are watching only one of them. `std::vector` creates its elements by *copy-constructing* them from the *original* element you supplied. For that purpose, the copy-constructor of class `A` is called 5 times in your example.

The copy-constructor for `A` in your example is implicitly declared and defined by the compiler. If you so desire, you can declare and define it yourself. If you print something from it, you will see that it is called at least 5 times.

Comment: Assuming no resizing, would it be 5 times or just 4 times? Is the original copy used?

Comment: @Mysticial: I don't expect any compiler to be able to use the original directly. How? The elements are stored in a dynamic memory block, which is allocated *after* the original element is constructed. So, all 5 elements have to be copied from the original.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you're right since it's in the wrong scope.

Answer (score 12):

It gets called once since the line

```
vector<A> v(5,A(1));
```

will call the constructor and the line becomes
    vector v(5,X);

where X is the object constructed after calling the constructor.

After that the copy constructor is used.

Try adding

```
A(const &A);
```

To the class declaration to verify this.